# Issue with css visiblity on object HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `upgrade` objects with html inside them like such:

```
{
    name: "Energy Drinks",
    desc: "The pinnacle of caffinated beverages, these drinks will squeeze a few more hours per day out of you.",
    moneyCost: 400,
    scienceCost: null,
    popularityCost: null,
    requirement: () => RESOURCES[0].amount >= 70,
    result : function() {
        player.moneyRatio -= 0.01;
        BUILDINGS[returnIndex(BUILDINGS, bumBuilding)].numberProdBase *= 1.33;
    },
    id: 'energyDrinksUpg', //Id used to fetch stuff
    html: `<button id="energyDrinksUpgButton" class="upgradeButtons">EnergyDrinks </button>     
    <div class='tooltip' id='energyDrinksUpgTooltip'> 
        <span>The pinnacle of caffinated beverages, these drinks will squeeze a few more hours per day out of you.<br /> </span>
        <span class='tooltipMoneyColor'> <span class='boldedNumbers' id='energyDrinksUpgMoneyCostDisp'> 30,000 </span> dollars<br /> </span>
        <span>----------------------------------------------------------------</span>
            <div>Money Cost Ratio: -0.01 </div>
            <div>Bum Counting Bonus: +33% </div>

    </div>` ,
    index: 1 //Index to determine what is deleted when you buy the upgrade. Based ONLY upon what order the table is sorted by.
 },
```

And I pass them through a function, as such. This function determines when to show and hide the upgrade buttons:

```
function checkVisiblityOnUpgrades() {
for (let iter of UPGRADES) {
    var currentUpgrade = iter;

    if (iter.requirement() && UPGRADESPURCHASED.includes(iter.id) == false) {

        /* Null Checks before updating html */
        console.log(iter.id);
        UPGRADESPURCHASED.push(iter.id);
        var table = getId('upgradeTable');    
        table.appendChild(tr = document.createElement("tr"));
        tr.appendChild(td = document.createElement("td"));
        td.innerHTML = iter.html;

        td.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
        upgrade(UPGRADES[returnIndex(UPGRADES,iter.id)]);
        });

        if ((getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("ScienceCostDisp")) != null))
            getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("ScienceCostDisp")).innerHTML = currentUpgrade["scienceCost"];
        if (getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("MoneyCostDisp")) != null)
            getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("MoneyCostDisp")).innerHTML = currentUpgrade["moneyCost"];
        if (getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("PopularityCostDisp")) != null)
            getId(currentUpgrade.id.concat("PopularityCostDisp")).innerHTML = currentUpgrade["popularityCost"];

        }
    }

}
```

Then, I have CSS that determines, if I hover over each button in the shown list, the tooltip will show. The tooltip is labeled in my object's html as `id = "____Tooltip"`. CSS is here:

```
#energyDrinksUpgButton:hover + energyDrinksUpgTooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* ... */    
}
```

Issue is that my hovering is not working. 
This happened recently when I shifted my html from fixed (in the html file) to variable (in the js file which is then added by function). Oddly enough everything else works: The actual upgrading of the item when clicking on the button, and the assigning of bonuses properly, seem to do the trick.

Thank you!

Comment: You're looking for `#energyDrinksUpgButton:hover + #energyDrinksUpgTooltip` instead of `#energyDrinksUpgButton:hover + energyDrinksUpgTooltip`. Note the second hash.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thank you!